# Storing/Moving photo to a separate app folder in the phone

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native

I am building a react-native app that takes a photo or choose a photo from Gallery and the photo should be moved to a separate folder called {appName} folder in the phone. I am storing all the images locally so it is critical that the image is stored in the folder.
For example: When you upload photo to Instagram or Whatsapp, the app will create a separate folder in the phone called Instagram/Whatsapp and store all of its photo in that folder.

I am using react-native to build the app, and image picker to take photo or choose photo from gallery.

I am currently trying on a simulator for Iphone, but I want it to work on both Iphone and Android.

I tried using 'react-native-fs' and  'react-native-fetch-blob'. But its not working correctly,

```
const dirPictures = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/hazelnut`;
//const dirPictures = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/hazelnut`;

const newImageName = `${moment().format('DDMMYY_HHmmSSS')}.jpg`;
const newFilepath = `${dirPictures}/${newImageName}`;

const imageMoved = await this.moveAttachment(this.state.image.uri, newFilepath);

moveAttachment = async (filePath, newFilepath) => {

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      RNFS.mkdir(dirPictures)
        .then( () => {
          RNFS.moveFile(filePath, newFilepath)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('FILE MOVED', filePath, newFilepath);
            resolve(true);
          })
        }) 
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('mkdir error', err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  };
```

The Image is moved, but it is not the behavior I want. Using the code above, it is moved to a document directory. But I want to move it to the photo directory. If I go into Photos, I should be able to see the app folder with all the images.

If I use const dirPictures = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/hazelnut`, then I get You don’t have permission to save the file “hazelnut” in the folder “undefined”.

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this :

```
const dirPictures = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/hazelnut`;
```

For android

And this :

```
const dirPictures = `${RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath}/hazelnut`;
```

For ios

Comment: I tried using that. It moves it to the folder, but I cannot see it in the Photos Folder in the phone. It  moves the image to the Library folder.